# Make Tablesorter work on Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger, blogspot

I've run into a problem trying to run the JQuery Plugin Tablesorter on my Blogspot Blog. I tried it with the example on the Tablesorter page to see if it would work at all. 
I wrote the following into the general html of the blog right before the closing  tag:

```
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'/> 
<script src='https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter/blob/master/jquery.tablesorter.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

I added the CSS directly to my blogs CSS as well. And it at least seems to be working (apart from the background image with the arrows in it, but it seems they are more tied to the actual script than the rest of the CSS, so it might just be an indicator of the script not working...)

Then I started a page and just kind of copy and pasted the following into it.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$("#myTable").tablesorter();});</script><br />
<table class="tablesorter" id="myTable"><thead>
<tr> <th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Due</th><th>Web Site</th></tr>
</thead> <tbody>
<tr> <td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>jsmith@gmail.com</td><td>$50.00</td><td>http://www.jsmith.com</td></tr>
<tr><td>Bach</td><td>Frank</td><td>fbach@yahoo.com</td><td>$50.00</td><td>http://www.frank.com</td></tr>
<tr><td>Doe</td><td>Jason</td><td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td><td>$100.00</td><td>http://www.jdoe.com</td></tr>
<tr><td>Conway</td><td>Tim</td><td>tconway@earthlink.net</td><td>$50.00</td><td>http://www.timconway.com</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

But well, it doesn't work. At all. I just get the table but there is no possibility to sort it. I tried in both Opera and Firefox to see whether it was browser specific but it just doesn't work.
To be honest: JQuery and JavaScript in general are not my strong suit but usually things do work if I'm following instructions. So I'm a bit at a loss here.
I've searched here but only found that it might be missing CSS. Which is there and more or less working. Or the fact that Blogger needs everything without spaces, which I tried but was automatically changed to the above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you check in the Chrome Developer Tools, you will see this:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter/blob/master/jquery.tablesorter.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

You are linking to a webpage (complete with all of GitHubs navigation bar, metadata about this file, etc etc), not to the javascript. The text file is this:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/christianbach/tablesorter/master/jquery.tablesorter.js

If you want it work in Chrome, you will need to use [RawGit](http://rawgit.com/) to get the correct MIME type:
https://cdn.rawgit.com/christianbach/tablesorter/master/jquery.tablesorter.js